# I need an itemRenderer for a ColumnSeries

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Can some one give me the code for an itemRenderer for a ColumnSeries currently my best effort is as follows...

Defining the itemRenderer

```
columnSeries.setStyle("itemRenderer","comp.EmptyBox");
```

comp.EmptyBox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    focusEnabled="true">
      <s:Rect id="lblData" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
          <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFCC" />
        </s:fill>
      <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x660099" weight="2" />
      </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```

And currently my error is a type cohersion due to a badly constructed itemRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
columnSeries.setStyle("itemRenderer", new ClassFactory(comp.EmptyBox));
```